# 1D Adaptive Mesh Refinement in C

Tags: c

I am a Physics PhD student currently entering the field of numerical relativity and I have to implement an adaptive mesh refinement code in 2 dimensions. As with every other bit of my program, I usually prefer to do something much simpler to understand what is going on before jumping to a more sophisticated case. However, I still seem to be doing something fundamentally wrong.

My code performs (or at least should perform) the following procedure: I discretize the x-axis in N intervals of size h. Every time a point is computed, the program stops and computes that point again by changing the interval of size h to another interval with two steps h/2. The program checks if the results are below some user specified tolerance and, if not, the process starts again with step size h/4 and so on. The following sketch illustrates the procedure

[image: sketch]

After the refinement function acts, I have absolutely no interest in keeping the values of the function on the refined grids. All I want is to compute the function on the coarse grid with maximum accuracy (in the image all I want to keep - and change - are the values of the black dots of the coarse [base] grid).

Unfortunately I see no improvement on the solution after the refinement algorithm is passed. I do not expect the plot of the function to be perfect, but I expect every point to be very close to the analytic solution. This is my refinement function (the function is called recursively until a maximum level of refinement - user specified - is reached):

```
void refine( int l, long double dx, long double x_min, long double x_max, long double f_min, long double *f_max ){
  // l = level of refinement, dx = step size, x_min is current x position, x_max = point we want to calculate, f_min = function evaluated at x_min, f_max = function evaluated at x_max
  int i;
  long double *f_aux, f_point;

  f_aux = (long double *) malloc ( (2*l + 1) * sizeof (long double) );

  dx = 0.5 * dx;

  f_aux[0] = f_min;
  for( i=1; i<2*l+1; i++ ){
    f_aux[i] = ( 1.0 - 2.0 * dx * ( x_min + (i-1)*dx - X0 ) / DELTA ) * f_aux[i-1];
  }

  if( l < lMAX ){
    if( fabs( f_aux[2*l] - *f_max ) > TOL ){
      f_point = f_aux[2*l];
      free( f_aux );
      l++;
      refine( l, dx, x_min+dx, x_max, f_min, &f_point );
    }
    else{
      *f_max = f_aux[2*l];
      free( f_aux );
    }
  }
  else{
    *f_max = f_aux[2*l];
    free( f_aux );
  }

  return;
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on the problem? I feel completely stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no language like C/C++. Your code is plain C.

Comment: Sorry, changed it.

Comment: I don't want to come over as patronising, but as a PhD student where C is clearly an important part of your **very interesting topic!** (now that takes me back), you *must* read K & R from cover to cover and complete all the example exercises. Your coding currently is holding you back. Sadly, to answer this will take far too long - really therefore I feel this question is a little too broad for this site.

Comment: @Bathsheba -- I'm trying to remember, does K & R advocate casting the result of `malloc()`?

Comment: @DavidBowling Absolutely not.

Comment: Can you please provide us a sample input and your expected outcome?

Comment: For example, I try to solve a differential equation f'(x) = - A * (x-X0) * f(x), which has as solution a normal distribution. I use finite difference techniques (in this case forward difference, but my main application would be for central differences).

Comment: Did you check scientific functions in C. You might get it and utilize it instead writing your own function.

Comment: @L.Werneck: I have a book behind me in my study on finite difference methods - it runs to some 500 pages. You really do need to study this stuff carefully. E.g. what is motivating you to use a subtractive tolerance rather than a multiplicative one? And calling `free` explicitly on all control paths is a maintenance headache. Can you not use C++ where the memory management is easier? C++ was used to model the wormhole in the film Interstellar, for example.

Comment: To be honest I am fairly new to programming. The two programming languages I am most familiar with are C and Fortran 95. I find Fortran 95 particularly simpler (and more intuitive) for most purposes, but since my collaborators are working in C I am forced to use it as well. But I must admit I am far, far from being a "fluent" user on either of them.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how the procedure you have written can be characterized as a "refinement", and I don't recognize the form of the expression by which you are computing new values for `f_aux[i]`, so I find it a bit suspect.  However, I think the reason you don't see changes when you apply this function is that it when it in fact does recurse, it ignores the updated value returned via the last parameter.  In other words, I don't see the point of `f_point`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your iteration enhances around last point, but is still coarse around start point:

```
*---------------* refine 0

*-------*-------* refine 1

*-------*---*---* refine 2

*-------*---*-*-* refine 3
```

And as your equation looks hyperbolic (depends on all previous iterations) the solution error will be cumuluative in nature. I think you shall iterate with fine grid from the begining to get proper solution - not only around neighborhood. Eg. for simple equation df/dx=f with such implementation:

```
float update(float f_prev, float dx, float /* unused */ target_dx) {
    return f_prev*dx + f_prev;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 8;
    float dx = 2.f/(float)(n-1);
    float f[n];
    f[0] = 1.f;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        f[i] = update(f[i-1], dx, dx / 16.f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would go with simple recursive formula:

```
float update_recursive(float f_prev, float dx, float target_dx) {
    if (dx > target_dx) {
        return update_recursive(
            update_recursive(f_prev, dx / 2.f, target_dx), dx / 2.f, target_dx
        );
    }

    return dx * f_prev + f_prev;
}
```

The approach enhances the quality of solution. The terminating condition may be more adaptive to solution than target_dx is. Of course, it is needed to ensure that recursion is well bounded.